# Date and time is not automatically updating on Macbook

Tags: macos, timezone

Since last week (as of 1 November 2023), my MacBook has been showing the wrong date & time.
When I set the time & date automatically it shows a date that is 15 days. If I set the time & date manually, then on restart it again shows the wrong time.

Location services are **on** for everything. VPN is not active (warp Cloudflare).

Now every thing whenever I turn **on** the MacBook or restart the date & time, it resets incorrectly and I have to run this command in Terminal.

`sudo sntp -sS time.apple.com`
or
`sudo sntp -sS time.google.com`

but it's annoying to run every time and check the date & time.

I have the latest beta version (Version 14.2 Beta (23C5030f)) but I never faced this issue before with a beta version.

How do I fix it?

[image: Screenshot of the Date & Time settings in macOS Sonoma 14.2 Beta showing the option 'Set time and date automatically' turned on]

Comment: If it's only happening on a beta, revert to last release & test again - then report the bug to Apple.

Comment: What is in `/etc/ntp.conf`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "it resets incorrectly"? How exactly do date/time differ from what you expect.

Comment: If the time is off in hour increments, check to see if the correct timezone selected.

Comment: @nohillside ntp.conf file have server time.apple.com.

Comment: @IconDaemon , Yes, as you can see in screenshot time zone is selected (GMT+5:30).